# Show that $\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n$ has a finite limit when $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am trying to show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n)$ exists as part of a much bigger problem. I could really use some help.

My attempt: I tried to use the fact that $1+ \frac {1}{2}+ \frac {1}{3}+ ... +\frac {1}{n} - \log n$ exists, but I got nowhere.

Comment: Stirling's Approximation: ln(N!)~ N (ln(N)-1) for N>>1. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I cannot use Stirling's Approx because that is the larger problem I am working on in a round about way. I should have said that.

Comment: One option is to consider $$\int_1^n \log \lceil t\rceil - \log t \, dt = \sum_{k = 2}^n \int_{k-1}^k \log (k+1) - \log t\,dt$$ and use what you know about $\log \frac{k+1}{t}$.

Comment: Let $x_n=\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n$. Patiently computing a simple equivalent $z_n$ of $x_{n+1}-x_n$ and checking that the series $\sum\limits_nz_n$ converges is not that difficult. Did you try? (The only required knowledge to do so is that $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3+o(x^3)$ when $x\to0$.)

Comment: @Did No I will try that, thank you.

Comment: If IRC, this result is due to DeMoivre, and it shows $n!\sim c(n^n/e^n) \sqrt n $ for some constant $c.$ Stirling later showed $c=\sqrt {2\pi}.$

Comment: @User52525 How do you complete the two missing steps of the accepted answer?

Comment: ((The approach delineated in my previous comment yields $$z_n\sim\frac1{12n^2}$$ hence indeed the result follows.))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** If you set
$$
u_n:=\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n,\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots,
$$ then you may prove that

> $$
> u_{n+1}-u_n=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right) \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq0 \tag1
> $$

implying the sequence $\left\{u_n\right\}$ is decreasing. On the other hand, you have

> $$
> u_n\geq0. \tag2
> $$

Thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}u_n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n)$ exists.

---

**Edit.** Let's give some details.

- Proof of $(1)$. Setting $\displaystyle f(x):=\frac{2x}{x+2}-\log(1+x),\, x  \in [0,1],$ we have $$ f(0)=0, \quad
     f'(x)=\frac{-x^2}{(x+2)^2(x+1)}\leq0 \quad  \implies f(x)\leq0, \quad
     x \in [0,1], $$ giving, for $n\geq1$,  $$
     u_{n+1}-u_n=\left(\frac12+n\right)\underbrace{\color{#C00000}{\left(\frac1{\frac12+n}
     -\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}}_{\large \color{#C00000}{f\left(\frac1n
     \right)} \leq\:\color{#C00000}{0}} \leq \color{#C00000}{0} .$$
- Proof of $(2)$. One may observe that, for $n\geq1$,$$
  \begin{align}
  &u_n=\log n! - (n+1/2)\log n + n\\
  &=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k-\int_{\frac12}^{n+\frac12}\log x\,\mathrm{d}x+(n+1/2)\log \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)+\frac12\log 2\\
  &=\underbrace{-\sum_{k=1}^nk\int_0^{\frac1{2k}}\log\left(1-x^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\large \color{blue}{\geq \:0}}+\underbrace{(n+1/2)\log \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)+\frac12\log 2}_{\large \color{blue}{\geq \:0}}\color{blue}{\geq 0}.
  \end{align}
  $$

Comment: How do you show $u_n\geq 0$?

Comment: This answer states with no justification that $$\log n! - \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log n + n\ge0$$ and that $$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ge1.$$ Are these two inequalities obvious from simple estimates?

Comment: Note in particular that the first inequality would yield a weak form of Stirling inequality (valid for every $n$, but only a lower bound) and that the OP's stated goal is to prove Stirling.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following equation
$$
\begin{align}
&\color{#C00000}{\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\log\left(n+\tfrac12\right)-\left(n+\tfrac12\right)-\tfrac12\log\left(\tfrac12\right)+\tfrac12}\color{#00A000}{-\log(n!)}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\int_{\frac12}^{n+\frac12}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\color{#00A000}{-\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-\frac12}^{k+\frac12}\log\left(\frac xk\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\int_0^{\frac1{2k}}\log\left(1-x^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\int_0^{\frac1{2k}}O\!\left(x^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\,O\!\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nO\!\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\\
&=C+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Since the right side of $(1)$ converges as $n\to\infty$, so does the expression on the left.

From the expression on the left side of $(1)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\log\left(n+\tfrac12\right)
&=\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\left[\log(n)+\tfrac1{2n}+O\!\left(\tfrac1{n^2}\right)\right]\\[6pt]
&=\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\log(n)+\tfrac12+O\!\left(\tfrac1n\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\log(n)-n-\log(n!)\right]=C-\tfrac12\log(2e)\tag{3}
$$
exists and is finite.